# How is nice/renice supposed to work? Am I misunderstanding?

Tags: macos, cpu-usage, nice

I run two extremely CPU-heavy (but not memory or I/O heavy) task on my Macbook Pro with 12 cores. This made the computer unusable for other tasks. I therefore reniced these processes to 20 and set Firefox to -1 (all other processes are 0 or lower), but Firefox is still extremely laggy. Shouldn't Firefox get all CPU time it requires when its nice-value is the lowest among all running processes?

Comment: If you're low on free RAM and the system is heavily swapping in/out, renicing processes most likely will not help. Renice will also not help if you're running a heavy GPU application.

Comment: OP specifically said they were not low on memory.   Renice might still help.  From comments, it probably didn't help a lot because they didn't renice enough processes.

Answer (score 1):

From the direction you changed the nice numbers, I think you understand nice.

However, nice doesn't fix latency, and there may be other unidentified bottlenecks (like disk I/O even if your heavy job doesn't appear to do that) which could be causing issues.

Some unixes support an interactive scheduling algorithm which prioritizes low latency over cpu use, and can give a job less cpu, but in a high priority bursty way.  Some of this call this a 'real time' priority.  I'm not aware if MacOS supports this and I haven't seen a way to adjust it in the MacOS GUI.

Comment: Renice doesn't affect allreay existing subprocesses do it? Firefox spawns dozens of subprocesses, I was thinking that maybe these subprocesses are the bottleneck?

Comment: Renice only affects the process you renice.  New subprocesses would inherit that, however.  You can renice them all at once if you want.

Comment: Does renice support process names (c.f. kill/killall) and wildcards? Or how do you mean I can renice them all?

Comment: renice can accept a list of process id's.  You can generate that with pgrep, ps|awk, or cut and paste, or whatever other method is convenient.